# How to set up password-less SSH for all users

Tags: linux, ssh, remote

I can set up password-less SSH for a single user by doing the following:

1) Generate RSA key pair for the local machine in ~/.ssh

2) Copy the local machine's public key to the remote machine's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

But is there a way to do this action for *all* users? Perhaps doing the same steps as above in /root/.ssh or something? Or is there a good way for root user to deploy keys and modify authorized_key lists in every users' ~/.ssh directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide password-less access for all users to a single remote host, then OpenSSH supports host-based public key authentication that user's the host key of the client to authenticate to the server and /etc/ssh/shosts.equiv to authorize users.

There is a good guide on how to configure it here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Host-based_Authentication

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
for u in $USERLIST; do
    su $u
    ssh-keygen [options] -f /home/$u/.ssh/id_rsa
    scp /home/$u/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $REMOTEHOST:/home/$u/.ssh/authorized_keys
    exit
done
```

Of course this involves typing a lot of passwords for the scp.  You could do it all as root to avoid typing passwords (assuming your root passwordless ssh is set up), but then you'd have to `chown` everything:

```
for u in $USERLIST; do
    ssh-keygen [options] -f /home/$u/.ssh/id_rsa

    # assuming "users" is the common group on the system
    chown $u:users /home/$u/.ssh/id_rsa

    # use -a to preserve ownership
    rsync -av /home/$u/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $REMOTEHOST:/home/$u/.ssh/authorized_keys
done
```

And of course you need to make sure each user's home directory and .ssh directory has the correct permissions (on both machines) when you're done.